# Is it possible to compare *tuples* in the `WHERE` clause of a SQL query?

Tags: sql, subquery, row-value-expression

Is it possible to compare *tuples* (thanks, a_horse_with_no_name) in the `WHERE` clause of a SQL query? That way, I could convert this:

```
/* This is actually a sub-sub-sub-query in the middle *
 * of an incredibly complex stored procedure.         */
SELECT ISNULL(SUM(DT.DetailField), 0)
FROM   DetailTable DT
WHERE  DT.ForeignKey = ...
AND    EXISTS (/* I know this sub-sub-sub-sub-query *
                * will return at most one row.      */
               SELECT 'X'
               FROM   HeaderTable HT
               WHERE  HT.HeaderKey    = DT.HeaderKey
               AND    HT.HeaderField1 = ...
               AND    HT.HeaderField2 = ...)
```

Into something similar to this:

```
SELECT ISNULL(SUM(DetailField), 0)
FROM   DetailTable DT
WHERE  DT.ForeignKey = ...
AND    (SELECT HT.HeaderField1, HT.HeaderField2
        FROM   HeaderTable HT
        WHERE  HT.HeaderKey = DT.HeaderKey) = (..., ...)
```

Comment: Did you try to execute similar code with your real table names and column names? did it work? what message did you get?

Comment: Btw: you mean "tuples" not "tables" in your subject

Answer (score 5, accepted):

What you are looking for is inner join:

```
SELECT ISNULL(SUM(DetailField), 0)
FROM   DetailTable DT
INNER JOIN HeaderTable HT ON HT.HeaderKey = DT.HeaderKey
WHERE  DT.ForeignKey = ...
AND    HT.HeaderField1 = ...
AND    HT.HeaderField2 = ...)
```

Comment: I know what `INNER JOIN` is. But I like it better when there is only one table per query, because that way I can more easily follow the logic that led me to writing that query. Besides, I'm not extracting data from `HeaderTable`.

Answer (score 7):

Writing

```
AND    (SELECT HT.HeaderField1, HT.HeaderField2
        FROM   HeaderTable HT
        WHERE  HT.HeaderKey = DT.HeaderKey) = (..., ...)
```

is certainly possible. At least with Oracle and PostgreSQL

If you are uncertain if the sub-select returns more than one row, you can even change the `=` to `IN`

Comment: I am completely certain that the sub-select returns one row. It just returns more than one column... and I'm using SQL Server. :S

Comment: I don't use SQL Server, so you will need to try if that is supported

Answer (score 3):

It seems like you are trying to compare *records* not *tables* here. And in fact you are comparing *results* of queries.

It is totally possible with Oracle and MySQL. The following query is valid and do the job:

```
SELECT (SELECT foo, bar FROM wathever) = (SELECT fuu, baz FROM another);
```

It will compare fields one against one and return 1 if they all match (or 0 if they dont). If subqueries return more than one row, it will raise a SQL error. This expression can also be used elsewhere as in WHERE clauses.

#### Update for postgreSQL

As @tsionyx pointed out, in PostgreSQL a subquery cannot return multiple columns. It's feasible returning a row value type:

```
SELECT (SELECT ROW(foo, bar) FROM wathever) = (SELECT ROW(fuu, baz) FROM another);
```

Comment: Not valid for Postgres: `SELECT (SELECT 1, 2) = (SELECT 1,2);
ERROR:  subquery must return only one column;` `SELECT (SELECT ROW(1, 2)) = (SELECT ROW(1,2));` is the valid one

Answer (score 1):

Goran's answer looks best to me and I voted for it.  Just to add another option, since you're using SQL Server, a flexible way to grab multiple columns from subqueries is `outer apply`.  You can compare two values (a tuple) like:

```
select  *
from    SomeTable t1
outer apply
        (
        select  *
        from    SomeOtherTable t2
        where   t1.Stuff = t2.Unit
        ) sub1
outer apply
        (
        select  *
        from    YetAnotherTable t3
        where   t1.Stuff = t3.jetser
        ) sub2
where   sub1.col1 = sub2.col1
        and sub1.col2 = sub2.col2
```